# Basic Inequalities

Tags: inequality

> $$\frac{4-x^2}{4-x^{\frac{1}{2}}}\geqslant 1$$

$$4-x^2\geqslant4-x^\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x^2-x^\frac{1}{2}\leqslant0$$

$$x^\frac{1}{2}(x^\frac{3}{2}-1)\leqslant0$$

Either,

$$x^\frac{1}{2} = 0$$

$$\therefore x = 0$$

Or,

$$x^\frac{3}{2}-1 = 0$$

$$\therefore x = 1$$

In this way, I have identified two critical points - trying out values in between the two points and outside the range of these two points, I see that,

$$0\leqslant x\leqslant1$$

However, as intuitive from viewing the initial inequality itself, I have missed a solution; $x>16$. How can this solution be obtained through an algebraic method?

Comment: Your 1st step is only correct if $4-\sqrt{x} > 0$. Hence you may have to multiply the inequality by $-1$ as per the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality can be managed easily.

Let $\sqrt x= y\implies x=y^2$

We need $\dfrac{4-y^4}{4-y}>1\iff0<\dfrac{4-y^4}{4-y}-1=\dfrac{y-y^4}{4-y}$

If $4-y\ne0,$ we need $$0< y(1-y^3)(4-y)=\dfrac{y(4-y)(1-y)\{(1+2y)^2+3\}}4$$

$$\iff y(4-y)(1-y)>0\iff y(y-1)(y-4)>0$$

We need even number of multiplicand $<0$

If $0$ terms $<0, y>4$

If $2$ terms $<0,0<y<1$